# Can Enigmail automatically not encrypt email for multiple recipients?

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird, enigmail

I have Enigmail/Thunderbird set up to automatically encrypt email when I send it to a particular recipient. I have it choosing my keys "By Per-Recipient Rules" and "By Email Addresses according to the key manager". I've edited the rules, and have a single rule for my wife with "Encryption" set to "Always".

Thus, when I email my wife, it automatically encypts. When I email anyone else, it doesn't. However, when there are multiple recipients, and one of those is my wife, I get a dialogue window asking me to make a choice. Is there a way to automatically *not* encrypt such emails? That is, automatically encrypt when my wife is the sole recipient, otherwise, don't (supressing a dialogue window).

Answer (score 0):

This could help

*In the Set Enigmail Rules for field  To:, Cc:, and Bcc: you must enter the recipient email address you're writing the rule for*

https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/user-manual/configuration#Recipient_Settings

Comment: I don't understand how the link helps. Could you please write specific step-by-step instructions on how to solve the question? (And welcome to SU!)

Comment: you could try two rules https://www.enigmail.net/documentation/images/c/c2/5-07.png one with contains and one with exactly your mail's wife

Comment: That doesn't help. It still matches individual recipients.